# 'Finally' Block in Iterators

Tags: c#, iterator

Is there any way in a C# iterator block to provide a block of code which will be run when the foreach ends (either naturally of by being broken out of), say to clean up resources?

The best I have come up with is to use the using construct, which is fine but does need an IDisposable class to do the clean up. For example:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this Stream stream)
    {
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string txt = rdr.ReadLine();
            while (txt != null)
            {
                yield return txt;
                txt = rdr.ReadLine();
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`try`/`finally` works fine, so long as the caller is using a `foreach` or manually calls `Dispose` on the `IEnumerator<T>`. To be honest, if it's to clean up resources, a `using` statement is probably going to be the best way of doing it anyway - if you're using a resource which needs cleaning up but doesn't implement `IDisposable`, that's a concern in itself :)

There are certain restrictions on what you can do in iterator blocks, as [explained on Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Iterators/default.aspx), but it all works very nicely in most cases.

You may find [my article about iterator block implementation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) interesting in terms of how `finally` is translated.

Answer (score 0):

`try/finally` works in this case.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this Stream stream)
{
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(stream);

    try
    {
        string txt = rdr.ReadLine();
        while (txt != null)
        {
            yield return txt;
            txt = rdr.ReadLine();
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        rdr.Dispose();
    }
}
```